# Creating Minimum number and Addition Function of LinkedList

Tags: java, algorithm, linked-list, addition

I'm  having a problem with trying the logic and trying to write a min and additionMerge function and their recursive versions of the function that takes at least one list as an argument (the first node of the list). This will be a private helper function that is called by a wrapper function that is a member function of the LinkedList class.

```
public class LinkedList {

     private static class ListNode {

        public int firstItem;
        public ListNode restOfList;
    }
    private ListNode first;

   /**
     * Create an empty list.
     */

    public LinkedList() {
       first = null;
    }


      public LinkedList(int n) {
    first = countDown(n);
}

public LinkedList(String s) {
    String[] temp = s.split(",");
    for (int i = temp.length-1; i >= 0; i--) {
        first = insertAtFront(first, Integer.parseInt(temp[i]));
    }
}

public int length() {
    return length(first);
}

private static int length(ListNode list) {
    if (list == null) {
        return 0;
    }
    int temp = length(list.restOfList);
    return temp + 1;
}

public boolean contains(int value) {
    return contains(first, value);
}

private static boolean contains(ListNode list, int value) {
    if (list == null) {
        return false;
    }
    if (list.firstItem == value) {
        return true;
    }
    return contains(list.restOfList, value);

}

public int sum() {
    return sum(first);
}

private static int sum(ListNode list) {
    if (list == null) {
        return 0;
    }
    return sum(list.restOfList) + list.firstItem;
}

public int count(int target) {
    return count(first, target);
}

private static int count(ListNode list, int target) {
    if (list == null) {
        return 0;
    }
    int temp = count(list.restOfList, target);
    if (list.firstItem == target) {
        temp++;
    }
    return temp;
}

public void replace(int oldValue, int newValue) {
    replace(first, oldValue, newValue);
}

private static void replace(ListNode list, int oldValue, int newValue) {
    if (list == null) {
        return;
    }
    replace(list.restOfList, oldValue, newValue);
    if (list.firstItem == oldValue) {
        list.firstItem = newValue;
    }
  }

    public void insertAtFront(int n) {
      first = insertAtFront(first, n);
   }

  private static ListNode insertAtFront(ListNode list, int n) {
    ListNode answer = new ListNode();
    answer.firstItem = n;
    answer.restOfList = list;
    return answer;
  }

  private static ListNode countDown(int n) {
    if (n == 1) {
        ListNode answer = new ListNode();
        answer.firstItem = 1;
        answer.restOfList = null;
        return answer;
    }
    ListNode temp = countDown(n - 1);
    ListNode answer = insertAtFront(temp, n);
    return answer;
  }

  public void insertAtBack(int item) {
    first = insertAtBack(first, item);
  }

  private static ListNode insertAtBack(ListNode list, int item) {
    if (list == null) {
        ListNode answer = new ListNode();
        answer.firstItem = item;
        answer.restOfList = null;
        return answer;
    }
    //List answer = new ListNode();
    //answer.firstItem = list.firstItem;
    ListNode temp = insertAtBack(list.restOfList, item);
    //answer.restOfList = temp;
    list.restOfList = temp;
    return list;
  }

  public void concatenate(LinkedList otherList) {
     this.first = concatenate(this.first, otherList.first);
  }

  private static ListNode concatenate(ListNode list1, ListNode list2) {
    if (list1 == null) {
        return list2;
    }
    ListNode temp = concatenate(list1.restOfList, list2);
    list1.restOfList = temp;
    return list1;
  }

  public void filter(int item) {
    first = filter(first, item);
  }

@Override
  public String toString() {
    if (first == null) {
        return "";
    }
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(256);
    sb.append(first.firstItem);
    for (ListNode current = first.restOfList;
            current != null;
            current = current.restOfList) {
        sb.append(',');
        sb.append(current.firstItem);
    }
    return sb.toString();
  }

  private static ListNode filter(ListNode list, int item) {
    if (list == null) {
        return null;
    }
    ListNode temp = filter(list.restOfList, item);
    if (list.firstItem == item) {
        return temp;
    }
    list.restOfList = temp;
    return list;
}



     public int min() throws RuntimeException {

      if (first == null)
      throw new RuntimeException("List is Empty");
         else 
          return min();

        }




  // * A private recursive helper function that returns the minimum item in a
   * list whose first node is the argument list.


 private static int min(ListNode list) throws RuntimeException {
    if (list == null) {
        return 0;


        }


    }


  public void additionMerge(LinkedList l2) {



 }


 * Every node in the list that begins with node
 * node1 is increased by the ammount of the corresponding
 * node in the list that begins with node node2.
 * If one list is longer than the other, the missing nodes 
 * in the shorter list are assumed to be 0.

  private static ListNode additionMerge(ListNode node1, ListNode node2) {
          if (list == null) {
             return null;
            }


       }

}
```

Comment: So what exactly is the question?

Comment: are you sure you want to write them recursively?

Comment: If this is homework, then please don't expect us to write your code, or debug it.  And please to expect us to wade through screenfulls of poorly formatted code.

Comment: Thank you Stephen you have been very helpful...Jag

Comment: the code formatting is so bad i can't understand it.  particularly near the min function(s?) which is what your question is about.  how do you expect anyone to answer when you don't even format the code so it's readable?

Answer (score 0):

If this is not homework, then my advice is:

- Don't write your own `LinkedList` class.  Use the existing out, and add the extra functionality either as a helper class or by extending the existing class.
- If you do decide to implement your own linked list class, then you should beware of using recursion.  Recursion gives a neat soltion, but there is a major drawback with recursion in Java.  The JVM does not do tail call optimization, so a recusive algorithm that recurses deeply (e.g. recursively traversing a long list) is liable to cause a `StackOverflowError`.

Comment: This isn't homework, its an exercise from a teach yourself java book that has certain criteria, one of which is to use recursion, even though it states exactly what you said about stackoverflow. I was trying to figure it out without looking at the actual answer.